# How to create angular schema form checklist of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-schema-form

Not quite sure how to get this list to render. I am trying to create a form of checkboxes created from custom objects.

This is my first time using [`angular-schema-form`](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form) but I am getting no luck here.

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nP9BvPYGSSgnoivN3v2Z?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize', 'schemaForm']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Comment",
    "properties": {
      "comment": {
        "type": "checkboxes"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "comment"
    ]
  };

  $scope.form = [
    {
      key: "comment",
      type: "checklist",
      titleMap: [{value: "1", name: "First"}]
    }
  ];

  $scope.model = {
    "name": "Jon Snow"
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `checkboxes` field type. But there are two options to define a few checkboxes:

1. Usage of `boolean` field type
2. Usage of `array` field type by specifying `items` array.

I updated your code:

```
$scope.schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Comment",
  "properties": {
    "comment": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "first": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "title": "First Checkbox"
          },
          "second": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "title": "Second Checkbox"
          },
          "third": {
            "type":"boolean",
            "title": "Third Checkbox"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "comment2": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "Standalone Checkbox"
    }
  }
};

$scope.form = [
  "*",
  {
    type: "submit",
    title: "Save"
  }
];

$scope.model = {};
```

To have some checkboxes checked by default, you can use the corresponding property names as follows:

```
$scope.model = {
  comment2: true,
  comment: [{
    second: true
  }]
};
```

For more details please look at the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F5TrDmD5rdgkxXewftPI?p=preview).

Comment: so we cant use these?  the defined types?

Comment: https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#default-form-types

Comment: @TylerJones As I said in the answer, you should use `boolean` field type to create a checkbox. Please look at how exactly I defined the schema above. *Form type* column in the docs you mentioned just describes a logical type of component rather than a system type used in `angular-schema-from`.

Comment: @TylerJones In other words, I haven't said it's impossible to create a checkbox, but you should use `boolean` field type instead of `checkboxes`.

Comment: @TylerJones Please look at the first column in the table from the docs.